# glitch from React hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to build a countdown timer app with start/pause button using React hooks.

However, the interaction does not responds as expected.
As the screenshot of console.log shows here:
[image: screenshot]

In Event 2, when pause button gets clicked, `props.setIsPaused(true)` should set `isPaused` true, but console.log shows `false`. However, the value of `isPaused` in parent component gets updated to `true` according to console.log.

In Event 3, when start button gets clicked, `props.setIsPaused(false)` should set `isPaused` false, but console.log shows `true`. However, the value of `isPaused` in parent component gets updated to `false` according to console.log.
In this case, countdown timer does not start, I need to click start button for 2nd time to have it finally start the countdown.

I am totally confused by these actions out of my expectations.

Any ideas or thoughts what I missed or mistakes I have?

Thank you.

Here is the code of the child/parent component performing timer countdown:

```
// Child Component 
function TimerPanel(props) {
  const launch = React.useRef();
  var secLeft = parseInt(props.timerNow.min) * 60 + parseInt(props.timerNow.sec)

  const startCountDown = () => {
    props.setIsPaused(false)    // Once start button is clicked, set isPaused false
    console.log('props.isPaused inside startCountDown func: ' + props.isPaused) // This should be false
    launch.current = setInterval(decrement, 1000)
  }
  function decrement() {
    if (secLeft > 0 && !props.isPaused) {
      console.log('props.isPaused inside decrement func: '+ props.isPaused)
      secLeft--;
      var minCountDown = Math.floor(secLeft / 60)
      var secCountDown = Math.floor((secLeft % 60) * 100) / 100
      props.setTimerNow({
        ...props.timerNow, 
        min: minCountDown, 
        sec: secCountDown})
    }
  }
  const pauseCountDown = () => {
    props.setIsPaused(true)     // Once pause button is clicked, set isPaused true
    console.log('props.isPaused inside pauseCountDown func: '+ props.isPaused)  // This should be true
    clearInterval(launch.current)
  }
......
}

// Parent Component 
function App() {
  const [breakLength, setBreakLength] = React.useState(5)
  const [sessionLength, setSessionLength] = React.useState(25)
  const [title, setTitle] = React.useState('Session')
  const initialTimer = {
    min: 25,
    sec: 0
  }
  const [timerNow, setTimerNow] = React.useState(initialTimer)
  const [isPaused, setIsPaused] = React.useState(false)

  console.log(timerNow)
  console.log('isPaused in App: ' + isPaused)
  ..........
}
```

Comment: I think your expectations that react state updates are synchronous and instantaneous are what is leading you astray. React updates are asynchronous and processed between render cycles. When you console log `props.isPaused` you are simply logging the pro value from the ***current*** render cycle, not what you just enqueued it to be updated to for the ***next*** render cycle. If you can provide enough code for a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and ***Reproducible***](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) we can better help resolve your issue if you need more help.

Comment: @Drew Reese Thank you very much for the input.
so the update from React won't start until the next render cycle? is it the same for class component? The bug here is that if `pause` button gets clicked right before clicking `start` button, `start` button will not launch countdown. It needs to be clicked for the 2nd time to have it start the coutdown. The code I pasted above is minimized removing JSX. I have this unfinished code on codepen where you can see complete code: [link](https://codepen.io/yuchit/pen/PoGVvvo) if you could give it a look. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it's the same for all react components. They all follow the component lifecycle. I'll take a peek at that codepen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues

I think what may've been tripping you up (I know it was me) was the split of logic between the app component and the timer panel component. All the state was declared in `App`, but all the state was mutated/updated in children components. I think some state was also poorly named, which made working with it a little confusing.

I've directly answered your concerns about the reflected values of `isPaused` being "delayed" in the comments, but I wanted to see how I could help.

## Suggested Solution

Move all the logic to manipulate the timer state into the same component where the state is declared, pass functions to children to callback to "inform" the parent to do some "stuff".

In the following example I was able to greatly reduce the burden of `TimerPanel` trying to compute the time to display and trying to update it and keep in sync with the paused state from the parent.

TimerPanel

Receives timer value, in seconds, and computes the displayed minutes and values since this is easily derived from state. Also receives callbacks to start/stop/reset the timer state.

```
function TimerPanel({
  timerNow,
  title,
  startTimer,
  pauseTimer,
  resetTimer,
}) {
  const minutes = Number(Math.floor(timerNow / 60))
  const seconds = Number(Math.floor((timerNow % 60) * 100) / 100)

  return (
    <div className="timer-wrapper">
      <div className="display-title">{title}</div>
      <div className="display-digits">
        {minutes.toString().padStart(2, "0")}:
        {seconds.toString().padStart(2, "0")}
      </div>
      <div className="control-keysets">
        <i className="fas fa-play-circle" onClick={startTimer}>
          Play
        </i>
        <i className="fas fa-pause-circle" onClick={pauseTimer}>
          Pause
        </i>
        <button className="reset" onClick={resetTimer}>
          Reset
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

App

Simply timer state to be just time in seconds as this makes time management much simpler. Create handlers to start, pause, and reset the timer state. Use an `useEffect` hook to run the effect of starting/stopping the time based on the component state. Do correct state logging in an `useEffect` hook with appropriate dependency.

```
function App() {
  const [breakLength, setBreakLength] = React.useState(5);
  const [sessionLength, setSessionLength] = React.useState(25);
  const [title, setTitle] = React.useState("Session");

  const initialTimer = 60 * 25;
  const [timerNow, setTimerNow] = React.useState(initialTimer);
  const [isStarted, setIsStarted] = React.useState(false);

  const timerRef = React.useRef();
  const start = () => setIsStarted(true);
  const pause = () => setIsStarted(false);
  const reset = () => {
    setIsStarted(false);
    setTimerNow(initialTimer);
  }
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("isStarted in App: " + isStarted);
    if (isStarted) {
      timerRef.current = setInterval(() => setTimerNow(t => t - 1), 1000);
    } else {
      clearInterval(timerRef.current)
    }
  }, [isStarted]);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('timer', timerNow);
  }, [timerNow])

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>Pomodoro Timer</h1>
      <div className="group">
        <div className="block">
          <BreakLength
            breakLength={breakLength}
            setBreakLength={setBreakLength}
            isPaused={!isStarted}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="block">
          <SessionLength
            sessionLength={sessionLength}
            setSessionLength={setSessionLength}
            timerNow={timerNow}
            setTimerNow={setTimerNow}
            isPaused={!isStarted}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="bottom-block">
        <TimerPanel
          title={title}
          setSessionLength={setSessionLength}
          timerNow={timerNow}
          startTimer={start}
          pauseTimer={pause}
          resetTimer={reset}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I left the `BreakLength` and `SessionLength` components intact as they don't appear to be utilized much yet.

## Demo

[image: Edit glitch-from-react-hooks]

Comment: Wow! Your code is so much more tidy and cleaner! I have so much more to learn. I think the biggest difference is that I tried to have all the logic running in the child component while all the states are declared in the parent component. This makes me wonder if it's much more straight and simpler to just have everything in one component instead of splitting them into separate children components. Also using `isStarted` to control the main logic in `useEffect` is a different concept than I had. By far, I am still not so clear when is a good time to use useEffect. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: @yuchit Thanks. I really did try to salvage what you had and make it work, but I think it was just a bit too convoluted. I think generally you should keep the logic that operates on an object (i.e. state) with the object, passing the state and callbacks for children to pass back any data the parent should update state with. This is how the parent is able to maintain central control over the state. Cheers.

Comment: yes, I agree. I was not aware it would require another cycle by passing data back from the child, which causes the unwanted glitches. I guess the safest strategy is to have the update on states stay central in the parent.